# How to create fake reflections?

Tags: effects, reflection

How can I create fake reflections easily like the one here:

[image]

Any online or easy open source tools out there?

Comment: [This tutorial](http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/3d/add-depth-of-field-to-a-3d-scene-with-lens-blur/) should give you more than what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I found other great tools and instructions here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet_floor_effect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an implied floor with light](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/creating-an-implied-floor-with-light)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use [this guide](http://styrizo.deviantart.com/art/Reflections-Master-63910377). It's quite fast and easy; you just have to put your text or file which you want to reflect, download this style and use it whenever, wherever you want.

Answer (score 7):

In Photoshop, copy the image, flip it, and apply a gradient opacity mask. You can do the same in Illustrator (you have to kind of hunt for the opacity mask under the "Transparency" tab.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using GIMP, I've created some pictures (== 1000 words * 5) that should show the process:

EDIT: Just be sure to start with a *transparent* background. I made the mistake of starting with a white background, but I fixed it using `Colours->Colour To Alpha`. Alternatively, if you're insane, you can use `Channels` or something similar.

1. Copy your image into a new layer, and `Image->Transform->Flip Vertically` (or `Layer->Transform->Flip Vertically`). Optionally, if you want to rotate it so that it corresponds to a different angle of rotation, use `Image->Transform->Guillotine` (or `Layer->Transform-> Arbitrary Rotation`), too. Notice the distance between the original and reflection; the more this distance is, the further away the surface of reflection looks.

   [image: Copy your image into a new layer, and Image-Transform-Flip Vertically (or Layer-Transform-Flip Vertically). Optionally, if you want to rotate it so that it corresponds to a different angle of rotation, use Image-Transform-Guillotine (or Layer-Transform- Arbitrary Rotation), too. Notice the distance between the original and reflection; the more this distance is, the further away the surface of reflection looks.]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]
5. Add a background layer.

   [image: Add a background layer.]

Comment: A little bit of blur helps, too, depending on the exact look you want.