# Help me recreate this text effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, reflection

I'm trying to learn and practice Photoshop in my free time. Been trying to recreate the text effect used on Gizmodo Brazil's logo but can't quite get it right. Can somebody guide me through?

Here's the logo:

[image: Gizmodo Brasil Logo]

Comment: I think it would help to state what you have tried so far and what you have problems with. Or maybe also provide an image of it and not only of the desired result. As it stands it sounds like a tutorial request, which is not the purpose here (and there are plenty tutorials on the web about specifically this).

Comment: This question has already been answered here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1087/how-to-create-fake-reflections

Comment: Madge, what effect do you mean? The reflection or the text itself?

Comment: Step 1: find a time machine and go back to 2001. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're referring to the reflection, the best way is probably to:

1. Create a smart object from your logo/image
2. Duplicate the smart object
3. Flip the duplicate vertically and move it down to line up the edges
4. Create a layer mask for the duplicate (show all)
5. Select the layer mask, then use the gradient tool (with a black-to-white gradient) to create the fade-out effect.

Or, you could just use a ready-made Photoshop action. Here's one: http://www.panosfx.com/free-photoshop-actions/reflections

Answer (score -3):

There is also great resource about Photoshop actions and retouching: https://foto-guru.com/photoshop-actions-complete-guide-2017/

Comment: Hi Ustin, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!

Comment: There was explanation how to solve this with actions, but bo explanation how to use actions. This site have both answers

Comment: Please read my comment. We do not appreciate answers relying on a link, for the link may break. Thank you for understanding.